# How to format DateTime as yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss (01-24 hours)?

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I'm calling a Java-based API. It's throwing a validation exception for a DateTime.

> Required format is: yyyy-MM-dd **kk**:mm:ss

Where `kk` formats hours between `01:00` and `24:00`, NOT (`00:00`-`23:00`).

This is not a typo, it's an acceptable pattern letter for [Java's SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**Is anyone aware of a good format string or an extension method to accomplish this in C#?**

Comment: In C# `HH` will format hours in 24 hour format with a leading zero https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Even in Java, `HH` is used for `00-24 hours` format.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [custom format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) have no support for that. You'll have to cobble something together yourself for the hours part.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a typo?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify I'm looking for  (01:00-24:00) NOT (00:00-23:00)

Comment: @Case You're right. I didn't know that format was supported in Java. +1

Comment: Does that mean 00:30 would be formatted as 24:30? That's *very* odd. (Formatting *just* 00:00 as 24:00 would make a little more sense.) Maybe it really does though. Weird.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's exactly what I was thinking but apparently, [that's what `kk` does in Java](https://rextester.com/GWD43860)? I don't really know Java though but it seems to be true. Still doesn't make sense to me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up using this smelly line of code:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").Replace(" 00:", " 24:");
```

Comment: I't smelly, it's quite ugly, it's duck tape but... It Just Works ™. Also, it's simple and understandable, I doubt that it can be done better. I would maybe wrap it in a method `FormatInThatStrangeJavaDateFormatRequredByTheAPI(DateTime dt)`, but finding a meaningful name can be harder that the implementation